# Ubuntu root directory automatically fills up

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, disk

My root partition automatically fills up while in use. I have a separate root partition with 105GB.

This is the second time I am facing this issue with Ubuntu 20.04LTS. Last it happened, after rebooting I was unable to log in anymore.

Disk analyzer shows var/log directory being filed up. But checking the directory for large files reveals nothing.

[image]

Update 1:

Here is a partial output of `ls -lh /var/log`. This part looks out of the ordinary as it shows something occupying 87G storage space.

```
total 87G
...
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  2.6M Jul 19 07:29 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  420K Jul 12 08:38 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  258K Jul  5 12:19 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp 286K Jul  2 09:15 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root 4.0K Sep  5  2019 openvpn
drwx------ 2 root              root 4.0K Apr 23 08:32 private
drwx------ 2 speech-dispatcher root 4.0K Jan 19 19:26 speech-dispatcher
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   87G Jul 19 14:53 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  1.5M Jul 19 07:29 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  387K Jul 18 07:27 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  581K Jul 17 06:35 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  200K Jul 16 04:49 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  403K Jul 15 07:18 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  423K Jul 14 09:41 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  123K Jul 13 07:29 syslog.7.gz
-rw------- 1 root              root    0 Apr 23 08:33 ubuntu-advantage.log
drwxr-x--- 2 root              adm  4.0K Jul  2 01:21 unattended-upgrades
...
```

The culprit seems to be apparent (syslog).
Is it safe deleting the file?
What is a permanent solution for fixing the huge size increase of syslog?

Update 2:

Output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog` as requested.

```
Jul 19 15:23:22 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=9999 txrate=21700
Jul 19 15:23:27 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=19500
Jul 19 15:24:36 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-61 noise=9999 txrate=21700
...
Jul 19 15:25:45 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-55 noise=9999 txrate=28900
...
Jul 19 15:30:01 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation CRON[18883]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Jul 19 15:30:19 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-75 noise=9999 txrate=19500
Jul 19 15:30:24 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=19500
Jul 19 15:30:25 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-59 noise=9999 txrate=19500
Jul 19 15:31:00 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-55 noise=9999 txrate=19500
Jul 19 15:31:40 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-77 noise=9999 txrate=21700
Jul 19 15:31:45 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-59 noise=9999 txrate=21700
Jul 19 15:31:45 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlx20e9170ef6cd: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-59 noise=9999 txrate=21700]
Jul 19 15:33:01 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation wpa_supplicant[813]: wlx20e9170ef6cd: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 0c:72:d9:3c:3b:62 [GTK=TKIP]
Jul 19 15:33:13 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jul 19 15:33:14 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation anacron[18959]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-07-19
Jul 19 15:33:14 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation anacron[18959]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jul 19 15:33:14 tobi-HP-Z400-Workstation systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: `journalctl --list-boots` please seems persistent journal is enabled.

Comment: `journalctl --disk-usage`
*Archived and active journals take up 112.6M in the file system.* @nobody

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260337/edit) to show the complete output of `ls -lh /var/log`

Comment: and `-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   87G Jul 19 14:53 syslog`  does not explain the size? Fix the problem that fills this file

Comment: @Rinzwind It does. I am not sure what to do. Is it safe to delete the file? What is causing the increase in size? Finally, what will be a permanent solution to the problem?

Comment: Run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and see what is written to that file. And add the relevant output lines to your question.

Comment: @TobiObadiah no. do what plumo says, investigate the errors and do a `> syslog` to empty it.  But do fix the issue.

Comment: possible solution https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1854588#p1854588

Comment: Fix the logging by wpa_supplicant it is set to log EVERYTHING. Only make it log errors. The link is a possible method